# Should i set null to object for delete from memory?

Tags: java, object, jvm

For example:

```
public class Box{
    public int id;

    public Box(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}

ArrayList<Box> boxArray = new ArrayList<Box>();

boxArray.add(new Box(0));
boxArray.add(new Box(1));
boxArray.add(new Box(2));

for (Iterator<Box> iter = boxArray.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Box box = iter.next();

    if (box.id == 1) {
        iter.remove();
        box = null;
    }
}
```

I know that: In Java, the JM is delete object when no referance.

But

1. Should i set "box = null;" to object in this code after remove it from array or not?
2. How can i make sure that the object will definitely remove from JM?

Comment: You don't, unless you know it is referenced somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Should i set "box = null;" to object in this code after remove it from array or not?

No.  It is a waste of time doing that.

> 2) How can i make sure that the object will definitely remove from memory?

You can't be sure it will be removed.  However, you *can* be sure that an unreachable object will be removed if the JVM *needs* the memory.  And that is all that really matters.

---

> I know that: In Java, the JVM will delete an object when there is no reference to it.

That's not exactly correct.  What we can say is as follows:

- An object that is no longer *reachable* by any live thread is *eligible* for garbage collection.  (This is not the same as saying that there is no reference to the object.)
- When the garbage collector runs, it will typically reclaim *some* unreachable objects, but not necessarily all of them.
- If the object has a `finalize` method, that method could cause the object to avoid being reclaimed.

All of this adds up to the fact that "will delete" is too strong.  Furthermore, the deletion won't happen immediately.

Answer (score 1):

> Should i set "box = null;" to object in this code after remove it from array or not?

No, there's no special need to do so since as soon as the for loop ends the `Box` reference doesn't exist any more having the same effect. Memory management is one thing less to worry about when programming in Java.

> How can i make sure that the object will definitely remove from JM?

You can't. The object would be garbage collected as and when the Garbage Collector feels the need to.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you should not. The "box" variable does not exist outside of your loop anyway.
2. You can't be sure that an object "is removed", nor should you care. Removing objects from memory at exactly the time they are not reachable would be **very** slow, GC prefers to work in batches and does its own book keeping.